# Trigger.io Security Especially for REST API

Tags: api, security, rest, authentication, trigger.io

I have just a thought running on my mind between this few days.

I am using trigger.io as our platform for our mobile application. And we are all using javascript as our scripting language for REST API.

Since we are using Javascript, all codes and especially account credentials (Api Key, Secret Key, etc.) can be seen if someone decompile the app and view the source codes of it.

I am wondering if any from trigger.io can answer, clarify and give us some concrete examples how to make our applciation secure from any malicious attacks(replay attacks, side-jacking, etc.) and account abused.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Key security is definitely a big concern with any app that runs on a user's device.

Pulling keys out of a Trigger.io app may be marginally easier than pulling keys out of a compiled native app, because your JavaScript is likely to be less obfuscated than compiled code. If you'd prefer to have your keys in compiled code, then you might consider a native plugin which just releases the keys to JS - http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/native/.

However, I wouldn't recommend that because it's still possible to pull secret keys out of compiled code - even obfuscating the keys in the binary is insufficient to frustrate a determined hacker.

The only way around the problem that we know of is to not include any secret keys in the app itself, but to have the user go through an interactive authentication step. Once that's happened and you know who you're talking to, your server can release the necessary keys to the app.